# `chemfig` customization and vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

In [this blog entry](http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/) by [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) I found a piece of code which redefines `chemifg`'s `\printatom` command to use `mhchem`'s `\cf` command, allowing (amongst other things) for sans serif typesetting.

This set-up requires the use of several `\vphantom`s to vertically align all bond lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\def\CF@node@content{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
    \ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\sffamily\cf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

% without \vphantom, bad alignment
\chemfig{-CH_2-CH_2-}
\medskip

% with \vphantom, nice alignment but lines too low
\chemfig{\vphantom{\ce{CH2}}-CH_2-\vphantom{\ce{CH2}}CH_2-\vphantom{\ce{CH2}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this puts the bond lines too low, such that they are not aligned with the center of the letters. Is there a way to align all the bond lines with the vertical center of the letters, just like the first line in the example without `\vphantom`?

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with your premise, but you will find, if you prepend the 2nd construct with `-$-$`, that the revised bond height is roughly comparable with the dash and the math axis.

Comment: You're right, the bond lines are just slightly below the math axis. But I guess the height of the math axis is chosen to look good with (mostly) lowercase letters in mind, while in chemical structures there are many uppercase ones. Anyway, to me the construct with `\vphantom` seems unnecessarily clunky. I might even be satisfied with the alignment, if it wasn't for the annoyingly clunky input.